# Python. Encoding to UTF-8 giving me extra characters

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I have a bunch of strings I have to insert into a sqlite database but many of them have some weird characters and what not. Now I can format it how I want but if I try to write this to a file I get.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 82-85: character maps to <undefined>
```

My code looks like this:

```
statement = 'Insert into {0} values({1})'.format(table,','.join(Insert))    
    print(statement)
    file.write(statement +'\n')
```

To note, Insert is just a table of column values. Now I can fix that error by encoding to utf-8 before writing:

```
statement.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

but then my text file I write to has a lot a extra characters, like b's before the text and '\' everywhere which I think is because its gets converted to bytes rather than a string?

Before encoding:

```
'Insert into table values ('Tue Nov 05 00:00:04 +0000 2013'
```

After encoding:

```
b'Insert into table values (\'Tue Nov 05 00:00:04 +0000 2013\'
```

I'm assuming I'm doing some sort of decoding\encoding wrong here but haven't hadn't any luck.

Comment: The `b` means it's a `str` in python2 and `bytes` in python3. What's the type of the item in `Insert`?

Comment: Its an array of strings.